# Assign value label to the shaping of a variable

Tags: r

I have a data frame "CB" with a column "gender" with two variables "Male" and "Female". 
I want that "Male" gets the value 0 and "Female" gets the value 1.

I did this:

```
CB$gender <- ifelse(CB$gender == "Male", 0, ifelse(CB$gender == "Female", 1, 
999))
```

When I look at the column I get this result:

```
head(CB$gender, 3)
[1] 1 0 0
```

That´s fine!

When I make a table I get this result:

```
table(CB$gender)

  0    1 
3555 3488
```

I want that 0 says "Male" and 1 says "Female"

For better understanding:

In SPSS it is possible to assign the value 0 to "Male" and the value 1 to "Female". When I print a table it looks like this:

```
Male Female
3555 3488
```

But the column looks like this:

```
gender
0
1
1
0
```

This is what I want.

Thank you!

Comment: `CB$gender <- factor(CB$gender, 0:1, labels = c("Male", "Female"))`. The column will still say `Male` and `Female` though. AFAIK, the way SPSS displays it is not possible in R, except when you call the column with `as.numeric(CB$gender)`.

Comment: `CB$gender = "Male"` is single equal sign a typo, should be `==` ?

Comment: If I use your solution I get: `head(CB$gender, 3)
[1] Female Male   Male  
Levels: Male Female` again. "0" and "1" for "Male" and "Female" are gone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `factor` to turn a variable into a factor and label it:

```
CB <- data.frame(gender= c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male"))
CB$gender <- ifelse(CB$gender == "Male", 0, ifelse(CB$gender == "Female", 1, 999))
str(CB)
#'data.frame':  8 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ gender: num  0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
CB$gender <- factor(CB$gender ,
                labels=c("Male", "Female"))
str(CB)
#'data.frame':  8 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ gender: Factor w/ 2 levels "Male","Female": 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 1
table(CB$gender)
#Male Female 
#   5      3
```

NOTE: R by turning into factors assigns levels from 1 (in this case 1 & 2)

Alternatively, you could use packages `lfactors`:

```
library(lfactors)
CB <- data.frame(gender= c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male"))
CB$gender <- ifelse(CB$gender == "Male", 0, ifelse(CB$gender == "Female", 1, 999))
CB$gender <- lfactor(CB$gender,
                 levels=0:1,
                 labels=c("Male", "Female"))
print(CB$gender)
#[1] Male   Female Male   Male   Female Female Male   Male  
#Levels: Male Female
#Numeric levels: 0 1 
table(CB$gender)
#  Male Female 
#     5      3 
attributes(CB$gender)$llevels
#[1] 0 1
```

Yet another option, closest to SPSS analogy, is to use package `labelled` and `sjmisc` as follows:

```
library(labelled)
library(sjmisc) #access to function to_label()
CB <- data.frame(gender= c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male"))
CB$gender <- ifelse(CB$gender == "Male", 0, ifelse(CB$gender == "Female", 1, 999))
val_labels(CB$gender) <- c("Male" = 0, "Female" = 1)
print(CB$gender)
#<Labelled double>
#[1] 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
#Labels:
# value  label
#     0   Male
#     1 Female
table(to_label(CB$gender))
#  Male Female 
#     5      3
```

Also, you can use a combination of packages `sjmisc` and `sjlabelled`.

```
library(sjmisc) #access to function to_label()
library(sjlabelled) #function set_labels()
CB <- data.frame(gender= c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male"))
CB$gender <- ifelse(CB$gender == "Male", 0, ifelse(CB$gender == "Female", 1, 999))
CB$gender <- set_labels(CB$gender, labels=c("Male", "Female"))
print(CB$gender)
#[1] 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
#attr(,"labels")
#  Male Female 
#     0      1 
table(to_label(CB$gender))
#  Male Female 
#     5      3
```

The function `to_label()` works similarly with the packages `lfactors`, `labelled` and `sjlabelled`.

Comment: Hi, if I use your first solution I get:  `Gender: Female, Male, Female....  ` in my column again.

Comment: The first option is the native way of handling factors in R, levels is what comes in, label is the outcome of factoring. If you cannot use the first solution, check out the other options which I added (packages lfactors, labelled, sjmisc and sjlabelled)

Comment: Even easier is using `sjmisc::to_value()`: `to_value(CB$gender, start.at = 0)` will convert factor to numeric, and keep the former factor levels as value labels. You can then use `sjmisc::frq(CB, gender)`, which displayes values and labels.